# Cuboid: Given Volume, Surface Area, length of one side / Find remaining sides

Tags: geometry

a, b, c - legths of sides
V - Volume
A - Surface Area

I need to find formulas, when to of the parameters are given to find out the remaining ones. I could already figure out the other ones, but can't come up with the last one. Here's how far I got: (given a, A, V)

c=(A/2 -a*b)/(a+b)

c=V/(a*b)

=>V/(a*b) = (A/2 -a*b)/(a+b)

Then I tried to get b, as the only unknown variable, on one side, so I get a formula... I tried it... for quite a long time. I just can't do it^^

I really hope you can help me :D

(Sorry for bad english or bad formulations, I'm german and it's my first post :) )

Answer (score 1):

Let the sides be $a,b,c$.

$$V = abc$$
$$A = 2(ab + bc + ac)$$

(there are three "varieties" of rectangular face, with two of each variety. The areas of each variety are every binary combination of $a,b,c$).

You're given $a$, so substitute that into the equations. Now you have a pair of simultaneous equations in two variables, which should be easy to solve.

Let's rename $a$ as $\alpha$ so it's clear that it's a distinct known quantity.

Now from the first equation:

$$b = \frac{V}{c\alpha}$$

Substitute that into the second equation:

$$\frac{V}{c\alpha}(c + \alpha) + c\alpha  =\frac{A}{2}$$

$$\frac{V}{\alpha} + \frac{V}{c} + c\alpha  =\frac{A}{2}$$

Multiply throughout by $c (\neq 0)$ to get:

$$\alpha c^2 + (\frac{V}{\alpha} - \frac{A}{2})c + V = 0$$

and solve that quadratic in $c$ using factorisation if the numbers are simple enough, or completion of the square or general quadratic formula if they're not so "nice". Discard any meaningless solutions, such as negative numbers. Use that value of $c$ by back substitution to determine $b$.

Comment: Thank you SO much. I used a wrong (or let's say unnecessarily complicated) way. I read your answer step by step and tried to work it out by myself. And I was very happy, when I then came to the same results as you. What I find very interesting is, that when you go on with the quadratic formula (c1/2=-p/2 +- ...), the two results you get, are both the remaining side legths; no discarding or back substitution needed. Again, thank you SO much :)

Comment: Ah yes, good catch. I should've anticipated that would happen. Glad to have helped but please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $V$, $A$, and $a$ are given. From $abc=V$  it follows that
$$bc={V\over a}\ .$$
Introducing this into  $A=2(ab+bc+ca)$ we obtain
$$b+c={{A\over2}-bc\over a}={Aa-2V\over 2a^2}\ .$$
Therefore, if such a cuboid is realizable, its other two sides $b$ and $c$ are the solutions of the quadratic equation
$$x^2-{Aa-2V\over 2a^2}x+{V\over a}=0\ .$$